# Self complementary graph with $9$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that in every self complementary graph with $9$ vertices there is at least one vertex of degree $4$. Only thing I found is number of edges and that is $18$. Not sure how to proceed, any idea is welcome.

Comment: It has the same number of vertices of degree $s$ as vertices of degree $8-s$.

Comment: In other words, there are as many vertices of degree greater than 4 as those of degree less than 4. Also, 9 is an odd number.